# Branch cuts of sqrt

Tags: functions, complex

I was trying to plot some complex functions with branch cuts on mathematica but I have two problems.

1) The function is with **z-Sqrt[z-1]*Sqrt[z+1]** with z complex. Now Mathematica says that the standard branch cut for the square root is chosen to be ]-inf, 0]. In this case I would expect to see the branch cut only between -1 and 1, but instead the branch cuts do not "cancel out" (mathematicians please don't kill me) before -1 (see picture, I am contour-plotting real and imaginary part of the function).
[image: z-Sqrt[z-1]*Sqrt[z-1]]
What is happening here?

2) If I try to plot **z-Sqrt[z^2-1]** I get a very strange function (see picture). I also have a branch cut on the imaginary axis, but this is due to the fact that if z=i, mathematica is forced to calculate the square root of -2, which is on the branch cut for the standard definition of the square root. 
[image]
Everything kind of fixes if I rotate the branch cuts by multiplying by -1 in the square root and by i outside. Of course now the branch cuts are ]-inf, -1] and [1, +inf[ but the function behaves like it should, but that is not what I want.

This boils down to understand how mathematica treats branch cuts, but I can't figure out why I have these strange behaviors.

Thanks everyone in advance!

Comment: I assume you mean `z - Sqrt[z - 1]*Sqrt[z + 1]` and not `z - Sqrt[z - 1]*Sqrt[z - 1]`.

Comment: yes, sorry. Fixed.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, I think M gets this one wrong.

We explicitly see where it thinks the branch cuts are:

```
ComplexAnalysis`BranchCuts[Sqrt[z - 1]*Sqrt[z + 1], z]
```

> ```
> Im[z] == 0 && Re[z] < 1
> ```

But it does look like the answer should be `Im[z] == 0 && -1 < Re[z] < 1`. We can use a `Manipulate` to look at cross sections:

```
Manipulate[
  Plot[
    Evaluate[ReIm[Sqrt[(x + y I) - 1]*Sqrt[(x + y I) + 1]]], 
    {y, -1, 1}, 
    PlotLegends -> {Re, Im}
  ],
  {x, -2, 1/2}
]
```

[image]

To manually fix this, you can use the option `Exclusions`.

```
With[{z = x + I y},
  ContourPlot[
    Re[z - Sqrt[z - 1]*Sqrt[z + 1]], 
    {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, 
    Contours -> 40, Exclusions -> {{y == 0, -1 < x < 1}}
  ]
]
```

[image]

### Edit

To answer the second part of your question, it looks like the correct branch cuts were chosen.

If I understand your question correctly, I think you're assuming $$ \sqrt{z^2 - 1} = \sqrt{z - 1}\sqrt{z + 1} $$ is always true. This is not the case (given that we're using the principal branch cut, as M does).

We can see the factored form of `Sqrt[z^2 - 1]` differs in phase angle, but has the same magnitude as `Sqrt[z - 1]Sqrt[z + 1]`:

```
PowerExpand[Sqrt[(z - 1) (z + 1)], Assumptions -> z ∈ Complexes]
```

> ```
> E^(I π Floor[1/2 - Arg[z-1]/(2π) - Arg[z+1]/(2π)]) Sqrt[z-1] Sqrt[z+1]
> ```

Comment: Hello Chip Hurst and J.M., thank you very much for the reply. I only have one additional comment on the second part. Forgetting about mathematica for a second, math tells us that one correct branch cut can indeed be [-1, 1], you can read this discussion about it

http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/184386/branch-cut-for-sqrt1-z2-can-i-use-the-branch-cut-of-sqrtz

So, choosing this branch cut, I should have a smooth function, without any jump in the phase. Moreover if you print the real part of the function for z=x + i * 0.00001, you will notice a wrong behavior for negative x.

Comment: @IntFabio The comments section states that the imaginary axes is also a branch cut if one chooses the branch for sqrt that way. We show this in Mathematica: `sqrt[z_] := Sqrt[z] (2 UnitStep[Im[z]] - 1)`. Now you can see the cuts here: `ContourPlot[Re[sqrt[1 - (x + I y)^2]], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}]`.

Comment: @IntFabio But to potentially answer your question, defining `sqrt[z_] := Sqrt[z] (2 UnitStep[Im[z]] - 1)`, you get branch cuts (-inf, -1], [1, inf) for your function in part 2.

Comment: Just to add to your last comment: you can rotate the branch cuts by writing the function as z- I * Sqrt[- (z^2-1)]   which effectively does nothing but correctly rotates the branch cuts. As for the second last comment, yes, if I choose that definition of the square root I should get the additional branch cut, but complex analysis tells us we should not get it. M might do it but you don't have that in formal math.

Comment: @IntFabio No, I think you do get it in formal math. See the first 2 comments [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/184434/93700). I think you'd have to find a different cut of sqrt to get the desired branch.

Comment: They also say that this additional branch cut can be removed. I am pretty sure, I have checked complex analysis books and I have asked fellow researchers. Sorry for bothering, it was just for completeness' sake. Thank you very much anyways.

Comment: @ChipHurst Are the branch cuts drawn by *Mathematica* really determined by ``ComplexAnalysis`BranchCuts``?  Or is ``ComplexAnalysis`BranchCuts`` just a novelty function not used anywhere?

Comment: @QuantumDot I have no idea actually. I used `TracePrint` on many plotting functions and it didn't appear to use it.

Comment: For the 2nd example, you can determine the branch cuts from: `With[{z = x + I y},
  ComplexExpand@
   Reduce[(Im[z^2 - 1] == 0 && Re[z^2 - 1] < 0)]] // Simplify`.